# $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})}{n}$ gives wrong answer in Mathematica?

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis

I wanted to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})}{n}$ on Mathematica and it says the sum does not converge, even though it does by Dirichlet's test. When I plugged the same sum in Wolfram Alpha, it returned  value of $-0,346\dots$, which is the expected value. Is this a bug in Mathematica, or am I missing something. Maybe I am using wrong syntax (picture attached). Also, does this mean Mathematica computes sums diferently, than Wolfram Alpha?[image]

Comment: You forgot to put a space between `n` and `π`, so `nπ` is treated as a single symbol rather than a multiplication of two. You can tell because `n` is supposed to be highlighted in a different colour (as you can see in the denominator).

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

sum = Sum[Cos[n*Pi/2]/n, {n, 1, Infinity}]

(* 1/2 (-Log[1 - I] - Log[1 + I]) *)
```

Simplifying,

```
sum = sum // FullSimplify

(* -(Log[2]/2) *)
```

which is approximately

```
sum // N

-0.346574
```

Alternatively,

```
Sum[Cos[n*Pi/2]/n, {n, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]

(* -(Log[2]/2) *)
```